VS Code intellisense is not recognizing modules?
I have a problem with some of my angular projects. On some of them. I have an intellisense error like the following:
'dx-data-grid' is not a known element:

This example is on the definition of a devextreme datagrid:
<dx-data-grid id="dataGrid"><\dx-data-grid>
The code tough, builds and runs without problems so it's only a visualization problem, which is a pain to see, all those red lines in the code.
I'm using angular 8.3.29, with node 14.20.1.
I read somewhere that it's some configuration missing, for example in the tsconfig.json and I tried working with it but nothing worked.
tsconfig.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@libs/*": ["library/*"],
      "@directives/*": ["directives/*"]
    },


  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  },

}

package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@mdi/font": "^4.7.95",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.7",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.5",
    "@ng-dynamic-forms/core": "^10.1.0",
    "@ng-dynamic-forms/ui-ngx-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^5.0.14",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^7.3.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^15.0.2",
    "@types/dhtmlxscheduler": "^4.3.40",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.25.2",
    "angular-draggable-droppable": "^4.3.10",
    "angular-file-uploader": "^5.0.2",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^8.0.4",
    "angular-tree-grid": "^2.8.7",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "bootstrap-fileinput": "^5.0.8",
    "chartist": "0.11.0",
    "core-js": "^3.1.3",
    "devextreme": "21.2.15",
    "devextreme-angular": "21.2.15",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.8",
    "ng2-completer": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-dragula": "1.5.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^5.2.0",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-select-ex": "^3.7.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.7.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.22",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.22",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }

This is only one of the modules it does it with, other modules as well just like this.
Do you have any suggestions?
